# How mosaic 1000 of rasters in a grid? sequentially by file name?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gis, raster, mosaic

I split my image (Raster image) into 1000 tiles for image segmentation prediction, and I want to mosaic the predicted rasters to a 1664*2432 grid sequentially.
I used these posts:

[Generate a Photographic mosaic from a given set of thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268756/generate-a-photographic-mosaic-from-a-given-set-of-thumbnails)

[How do you merge images into a canvas using PIL/Pillow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647311/how-do-you-merge-images-into-a-canvas-using-pil-pillow)

[PIL fill background image repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155087/pil-fill-background-image-repeatedly?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This is the code:

```
import PIL, os, glob
from PIL import Image
from math import ceil, floor

PATH = '/content/drive/MyDrive/classification/CNN_segmentation/big_Image/prediction'

frame_width = 1664
images_per_row = 26
padding = 2

os.chdir(PATH)

images = glob.glob("*.tiff")
images = images[:988]       
img_width, img_height = Image.open(images[0]).size
sf = (frame_width-(images_per_row-1)*padding)/(images_per_row*img_width)       #scaling factor
scaled_img_width = ceil(img_width*sf)                   #s
scaled_img_height = ceil(img_height*sf)

number_of_rows = 38
frame_height = 2432 

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (frame_width, frame_height))

i,j=0,0
for num, im in enumerate(images):
    if num%images_per_row==0:
        i=0
    im = Image.open(im)
    im.thumbnail((64,64))
    #Iterate through a 4 by 4 grid with 100 spacing, to place my image
    y_cord = (j//images_per_row)*scaled_img_height
    new_im.paste(im, (i,y_cord))
    i=(i+64)+0
    j+=1

new_im.show()
new_im.save("out.jpg", "JPEG", quality=80, optimize=True, progressive=True)
new_im
```

The result is a 1664*2432 image but all the pixels are black.
I tried to use, "im=rasterio.open(im)" instead of "im = Image.open(im)", but I faced this error:

AttributeError: 'DatasetReader' object has no attribute 'thumbnail'

I will be thankful if anybody could help me.

Note: I solved the problem by replacing RGB with P, but still do not know how mosaic the images by file name sequentially.

Comment: The error with `rasterio.open` makes perfect sense since that's a completely different object type. You'd have to use the `rasterio` documentation to see what the equivalent operations are compared to `PIL`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to use rasterio documentations. Unfortunately, I did not find any resource about mosaicing rasters into a grid in rasterio.

Comment: I solved the problem by changing Image.new('RGB', (frame_width, frame_height)) to Image.new('P, (frame_width, frame_height)).